# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telegram'

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

Trying to run the python-telegram-bot library through Jupyter Notebook I get this question error. I tried many ways to reinstall it, but nothing from answers at any forums helped me. What should be a mistake and how to avoid it while installing?

Comment: This is most likely an issue of virtual environments. Did you install Jupyter Notebook via Anaconda? Check in which virtual environment (and on which python version) your notebook runs and on which you installed the library. Also please paste your import statement because the mistake could be in that.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a directory with "telegram" name? If you do,rename your directory and try it again to prevent import conflict.
good luck:)